# How can I pass a string with spaces as a function argument in bash

Tags: bash, vim

I am trying to pass a string with spaces as `./triggerSparkApp 'Premier League'` via a bash script.

I implemented it in this way via bash script;

```
if [ $@ -eq "${0}" ]
  then
    echo "No arguments" 
  else
       spark-submit --master yarn-client --jars hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar spark-queries-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar "${0}" --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores     
 fi
```

The argument should be passed through in spark-submit before --driver-memory. As it is it is returning:

```
[: too many arguments
```

I would appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use quote around the `$@` in order avoid word splitting. And use `==` for *string* comparison; `-eq` for *integers*.

```
if [ "$@" == "${1}" ]
  then
    echo "No arguments"
  else
       spark-submit ...
 fi
```

Alternatively you can use `[[ .. ]]` in which word splitting is not performed.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I do not think the OP wants to test for argument value, but for presence.  Additionally, I do not think `$0` is what is really meant to be used (it is not the first argument, which I think is what the OP assumes it is).

Comment: The comparison with `$0` implies OP wanted check if entire arg is equivalent to its first i.e. the words are considered as a one argument. But you're right that $0 isn't what OP intended to use. Edited it. Rest, only OP can clarify.

Comment: This does work...but for some funny reason it outputs [[ Premier League: command not found....and still works

Comment: @EP89 `if [[ "$@" == "$1" ]]; then echo "all fine"; fi` is how it needs to look like.

Comment: There is never any reason to abuse `"$@"` like this.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want :

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "No arguments"
else
  spark-submit --master yarn-client --jars \
    hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar \
    spark-queries-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
    "$1" --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores     
fi
```

The `$#` expands to the number of arguments.  The first argument is `$1`, not `$0`, so I replaced that in the `spark-submit` command.  The `\` continuations are for readability only.

Another way I like to perform the argument presence test is this :

```
if (($#))
then
  spark-submit --master yarn-client --jars \
    hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.0.jar \
    spark-queries-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
    "$1" --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores     
else
  echo "No arguments"
fi
```

The `(( ))` test, when it contains an expression that evaluates to an integer, returns 0 (true) if the integer is non-zero, and a non-zero value (false) otherwise.